# Add a non-breaking space to "reopen (1)" and its ilk

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, whitespace

If you go to [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3372/will-there-be-a-continuation-of-sword-art-online) and are a 4k+ user on Anime.SE, you will see the following:

> [image: ew]

There is one reopen vote on this question, but the reopen vote count is displayed on a different line than the word "reopen". This is slightly silly, and would perhaps benefit from converting `reopen (1)` to `reopen&nbsp;(1)`, and likewise for close and delete votes. (Or any other way of preventing a line break between the vote type and the vote count.)

A repro (the close link) from here on Meta:

> [image]

Comment: Hmm, no repro here. Are you zoomed out by any chance?

Comment: @AnnaLear Nope. Windows 7 on Chrome 31.0.1650.63; no userscripts running on the site. Zooming in and out doesn't move the "(1)" back on to the same line as "reopen", either.

Comment: What's your screen resolution?

Comment: @AnnaLear 1920x1080

Comment: For what it's worth, I've seen this occasionally too.

Comment: Here's a full screenshot of the page on my machine (full-screened, but it happens even when non-full-screened): http://i.imgur.com/kcZ8qTi.png

Comment: [Similar/related issue on dba.SE](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/993/action-line-spreads-across-two-lines-when-too-much-going-on)

Comment: I've seen this occasionally on code golf but never bothered to report. +1

Comment: I've reproduced this, just by changing "mod" to "protect". Since the only breaking space is the one before the (1), that's where it wraps.

Comment: @Shog9 Ahhh. I somehow missed "protect".

Comment: @senshin I've looked up *ilk* in a dictionary but I still don't understand what the word means in this context.

Comment: @Stijn "and its ilk" = "and things of that sort", meaning "and also things like 'close (1)', 'delete (1)', etc.".  I'm sure [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) or [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/) would be glad to answer in greater depth if you want to ask there! :)

Comment: With the addition of the "rollback" link, [this can now be reproduced right here on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230000/223030).

Comment: @Anna is this Jin's area, or can any dev fix it? Just asking... ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard no one dev will fix it because it's too minor. No matter how many votes on the post.

Comment: @alexolut well, once upon a time I was optimistic... :)

Answer (score 12):

A big part of the problem is that the line *cannot* break at the spaces *between* the links, since they're not actual spaces, but rather `|` characters styled to *look* like spaces:

```
<span class="lsep">|</span>
```

A fairly simple way to fix this, without messing with the existing styles on various Stack Exchange sites (on some of which the `|` characters are actually visible, and on some of which they're not) would be to modify the code that generates the menus to insert a [Unicode zero width space (U+200B)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm) after each separator bar.  This would allow browsers to insert line breaks after the bars, making it much less likely that breaks get inserted *within* menu items.

You can test the effect of this change locally by opening the JavaScript console in your browser, while looking at a post affected by this issue, and running the following command:

```
$('.post-menu .lsep').append('&#x200B;')
```

As for the original issue of line-breaks being inserted inside menu links, a simple way to prevent that would be to add the following CSS rule:

```
.post-menu a { white-space: nowrap }
```

In fact, the zero-width spaces could also be inserted using the [CSS `:after` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after):

```
.post-menu .lsep:after { content: '\200B' }
```

---

**Edit:** I made that into a [user script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/248353) for GreaseMonkey / Chrome users.  All it [does](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/223804) is inject the two CSS rules shown above into all pages.  Here's a screenshot:

> [image: Screenshot]

(Note that the screenshot is also demonstrating [another user script of mine](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/223804).)

---

**Edit 2:** Turns out that `content: '\200B'` doesn't help in Chrome, but the following does:

```
.post-menu .lsep:after { content: ' '; font-size: 0px }
```

I've incorporated this new fix into a collection of various minor user script fixes and workarounds that I'm calling the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch).

Answer (score 7):

It looks like recent changes have fixed this issue.  We're using `display: inline-block` which seems to handle the line break issue.

Comment: So, status-completed then?