# Bad line break of close link when there's an edit

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, design, meta

When a question on Meta Stack Exchange has been edited, and is subsequently voted for to be closed, there is a line break of the `Close (1)` link between the word `Close` and `(1)`.

Example from [Tag input too low when editing on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229998/tag-input-too-low-when-editing-on-meta-stack-exchange#229998):

[image: Example]